# Trying to implement login popup but bootstrap modal is unclickable

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to add a login popup on my page but after it pops up, it's unclickable (input fields and buttons)

I'm pretty new to custom web app dev so i sourced a bit of the components.
I'm working on this project for a client as well as to sharpen my skills and branch out from the wordpress plug and play lifestyle

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Sedima</title>

<!-- Core CSS -->
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- popupstyles -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" media="all" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="loginmodal-container">
            <h2>Registration</h2>
        <form>
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
          <input type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Register">
        </form>

        <div class="login-help">
            <a href="#">Login</a> - <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Scrips -->
<!-- Core JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<!-- jQuery lib from google server ===================== -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts -->
<script src="js/grayscale.min.js"></script>


<!-- popupscripts -->
<!-- value controll and input masking scripts (will prolly replace with my own in future) -->
```

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TweenMax.min.js'></script>


<!-- custom scripts -->
<script  src="js/index.js"></script>
<script  src="js/login.js"></script>
<script  src="js/reg.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you do not use

```js
$(function() {
  console.log("DOM is ready!");
});
```

To wait until the document is ready.

Make sure your HTML modifications are done if the DOM actually is ready to do that.

Comment: Soory to seem like a complete noob but but I am....I build using divi which is why I'm brick walling :< So exactly what do I do with that code?

this is the error message i get in the console:

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: TimelineLite is not defined ReferenceError: TimelineLite is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/index.js:14:11)
    at l (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29375)

Comment: at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677) undefined
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: TimelineLite is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:14)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)